# Do I need "./" and "../" on HTML files paths?

Tags: html, hyperlink, path, href, src

I'm using relative URL in attributes like `href` and `src`. Do I really need to use `./` and `../` before the paths to correctly establish the link?

When I'm done coding index.html, I copy the code and use it on others .html files of my project. I find it frustrating having to correct every path then.

My projects folder structure is like:

```
website-project folder
      index.html

      css folder
          style.css

      img folder
           image.png

      about folder
          about.html
```

If I use `index.html` code to start `about.html` I need to change every path begging from `./` to `../`. Using "Find & Replace" tool makes it easier but still it would be nicer if I could link to paths based on the root folder and not the present folder. Ex:

Using

```
href="website-project/img/image.png"
```

inside `about.html` would link to `website-project/img/image.png` instead of `website-project/about/img/image.png` which leads to an error.

UPDATE JULY 07 2016

Inside `index.html` page if I make a `<a>` with `href="/about/about.html` instead of linking to:

`file:///home/guizo/Documents/website-project/about.html`

it links to:

`file:///about/about.html`

The same goes on for the others links:

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218879/link-a-css-on-another-folder/27218926#27218926

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
href="/img/image.png"
```

`/` refers to your root directory.

EDIT:
The above will not work for local static websites. In these cases, you should try using the `<BASE href />` tag which tags links on to a fixed base address. It can be used as follows:

For `index.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>index</title>
        <BASE href="file:///home/guizo/Documents/website-project/" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="about/about.html">Go to about</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

For `about.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>About</title>
        <BASE href="file:///home/guizo/Documents/website-project/" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="index.html">Go to index</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried it before and it does not work for me.

Inside `index.html` page if I click `Home`, instead of linking to:

`file:///home/guizo/Documents/website-project/index.html`

it links to:

`file:///index.html`

The same goes on for the others links:

`file:///css/style.html`; `file:///about/about.html`; `file:///img/image.html`

Comment: Thank you. That is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

try this '/img/image.png'. / represents root of the site.