# Module not found: Can't resolve

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a component with React.js and the console is throwing the following **error**:

**Failed to compile:**

```
./src/components/file_tree.js
   Module not found: Can't resolve '.src/components/directory.js' in 
'D:\Treebeard\src'
```

Here you can see the code inside **file_tree.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react';
import { Directory } from './components/directory.js';
```

The code inside **directory.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TriangleDown } from './components/file_tree.js';
import { FolderIcon } from './components/file_tree.js';
import { formatName } from './components/file_tree.js';
import { renderTree } from './components/file_tree.js';
```

And here, the **App.js** code, just in case:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { SearchEngine } from './components/search_engine.js';
import { FileTree } from './components/file_tree.js';
import { Directory } from './components/directory.js';
```

I checked the file paths from both files and everything seems okay, but this error is thrown. Am I missing something about the file paths? Both **directory.js** and **file_tree.js** are inside **'./src/components'** folder.

**App.js** is inside **'./src'** folder.

Comment: how are you exporting  `file_tree.js`?

Comment: @Maxwelll shouldn't matter at this point, you'd get a different error if it didn't actually export those.

Comment: @JaredSmith if you are by default exporting the component it would matter...

Comment: @Maxwelll you and I are working off two different definitions of "matter". You seem to mean "necessary to make the code work" and I mean "would produce the specific error the OP is asking about". AFAICT, we're both correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are accessing file path from same directory. It should be:

**file_tree.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react';
import { Directory } from './directory.js';
```

**directory.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { TriangleDown } from './file_tree.js';
import { FolderIcon } from './file_tree.js';
import { formatName } from './file_tree.js';
import { renderTree } from './file_tree.js';
```

**App.js:** It's okay. Since you're accessing components file path from the current directory.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { SearchEngine } from './components/search_engine.js';
import { FileTree } from './components/file_tree.js';
import { Directory } from './components/directory.js';
```

For further help, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218879/link-a-css-on-another-folder/27218926#27218926) which will help you in relevant case.