# Linking CSS in a different parent directory

Tags: html, css

I have a project I am working on that contains folders where I'd like to use the same CSS file on each without copying into new folders. The folders are set up in the following format:

Projects
   ---Folder 
      ----CSS (folder)
      --------Styles.css
      --------index.html
   ---Folder 2
   -------Index.html <---- I want to link to the `Styles.css` file in `folder 1`.

I've tried using: `href="../Folder 1/CSS/styles.css"`

It doesn't work. Maybe I am misunderstanding but I thought using `../` took you back one directory. Obviously I am doing something wrong.

I also tried .`./../Folder 1` just in case I was missing something and that didn't work either.

Comment: Try using, `href="../Folder/CSS/Styles.css"`

Comment: Is it a casing issue? In your example, the file is called `Styles.scss` (uppercase) but your href is `styles.scss` (lowercase). You should try again to post the full code - what problems were you having doing that?

Comment: No i just typo it on here. Its all lowercase.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this:

`------ folder home
-------- folder styles
---------- style styles.css
-------- page folder
---------- html 1-index.html
---------- html 2-index.html`

and everywhere the path would be one.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../folder styles/style.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

Refering to an answer here by Bhojendra Rauniyar: [Link a .css on another folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218879/link-a-css-on-another-folder)

check this: https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:

- Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
- Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
- Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts
  there (and so on...)
- To move forward, just start with the first subdirectory and keep
  moving forward

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It will only work if its inside the webroot of the project e.g. my guess is you have folder 2 as the websites root.

If you want to do it this way set up a domain for your resources and link them that way.

E.g. localhost/resources directory  otherwise set the projects root as project and this will work

Answer (score 0):

You have the folder named "Folder" on the post. In the code it is "Folder 1". Try changing oe of these.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your setup. First, check you spelling and case. This is all case-sensitive. Otherwise, the server will need access to the `Projects` directory and then you can step up and into the other projects.

Ideally, this would mean your URL would also have to include the project name as well.
e.g. `http://domain.local/project%201` - Note the `%20` used as a whitespace here.

The reason for this is how a server has permissions to view the website root directory. In a typical setup, the domain is mapped to the project specific directory. e.g. `Project/Folder 1` you would normally access this via a URL `http://domain.local/`. If this is your setup, your approach will not work.

You have two options.

1. Setup the server to use `Projects` as the webroot and all
   projects are in the URL. Personally, not ideal but this is really up
   to you.
2. Setup each project on it's own domain and reference that
   domain in your include. So instead of using `href="../Folder%201/CSS/styles.css"` you would use
   `href="http://domain1.local/CSS/styles.css"`

There are other setups you could possibly do but I would suggest these 2 options as most ideal. It just depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

### This works fine

---------------------------------------------------
ONE dot (.)
TWO dots (..) do not work
"./" go to the root of the current diretory
"././" go out of the root directory
Now select anything being in the parent directory

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).