# Importing node module vs custom component ES6, React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Can someone help me to understand how es6 import works?

As I know to import node modules I can write name of module without mentioning path ex:

```
import React from 'react';
```

However to import any custom component, I have to give path like:

```
import Header from "./components/Header";
```

Or to import scss

```
import "../../scss/components/Header.scss";
```

Can someone tell me how it works, why in case of nodule module I do not need to give path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do not give path it will directly look into `node_modules` directory and find the provided module.

So,

```
import React from 'react';
```

It will look into `node_modules/react` and import `React` from `index.js` since we have not explicitly defined any path after `react` directory. So, it is similar to `react/index.js`. If you have to import something else rather than `index.js` then we'll need to specify the file path as well. For eg. `module/somefile.js`.

Now, when you specify path that is starting with `/` or `./` or `../` it will not look into `node_modules` but it will look in to the directory. You may look into my [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27218926/2138752) for more detail how linking path works.

In the linked post, it has no `./` path described. So let me tell you that it will find the current project directory. For eg. your project folder is `app` and you specify `./mydir/myfile` then it will look into `app/mydir/myfile.js`. There's no need to specify `.js` extension necessarily if you have to import javascript file. It will automatically match the `.js` extension. But if you have to import other files for eg. `.css` then you must specify the extension as well.

Comment: Thank you @Bhojendra, as you said "when you specify path that is starting with / or ./ or ../ it will not look into node_modules" that clears my understanding about using node_modules, however i am still curious to know that how it works if we don't use / or ./ or ../ it will always look into node_modules, is it some kind of ES6 standard written for import?

Comment: It is executed on all node.js projects that is to say project  created with npm init or something else which has package.json.