# Where is React actually being imported from?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

The top of most React files has:

```
import React from 'react'
```

Yet `react` is not actually a file. So where is it and how is it being imported from nothing?

Comment: You've installed it via npm/yarn, right?

Comment: Yes, React is installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you import from `react` it first looks into the `node_modules/react/index.js` like other module looks for the `index.js` if there's no file specified. And you may also ask why does it look for `node_modules`? The answer is you have not specified relative or absolute file path for eg. `./components/MyComponent`. When you do not specify the specific path, it will look for the `node_modules` directory.

The `index.js` exports is like:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react.production.min.js');
} else {
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react.development.js');
}
```

So, let's continue with `development` environment. Now, when you look into the file `node_modules/react/csj/react.development.js`, you will find several **exports** statement at the end of the file.

So, you're simply importing `React` means you're importing all of them. And thus, you can use `React.Component`, `React.Children`, etc.

It's not necessary that you must have named `React` but it's standard. So, even if you do:

```
import ReactApplication from 'react'
```

You have access to all of them like `ReactApplication.Component`. Hope, this clears up things.

---

Further details:

- When you specify `./`, it will look for the current directory.
- When you specify `/`, it will look for the root directory.
- When you do not specify, it will first look to directory in your project and if it doesn't find, it will look into the `node_modules` directory.

Other post you may be interested to look into: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27218926/2138752

Comment: Thanks. This helps me understand that I have somehow misconfigured webpack, which is why I'm having this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62587472/why-is-webpack-unable-to-find-react-when-im-using-a-custom-entry-point

Comment: I have updated further which may help your query further. :)

Answer (score 3):

React is available as a dependency in the *node_modules* directory.

React must also be in the scope of files containing  JSX to enable transpilers like Babel know how to handle that syntax.

Answer (score 2):

React is installed as an npm package, so it can be found in your node_modules folder. That's where it's being imported from.

Comment: Why doesn't the path need to be `../node_modules/react` ?

Comment: Because everything is setup with web pack. So it knows to retrieve packages from the node modules by default

Comment: @dinakajoy It's a default nature of Node.js applications. So, even if you do not have webpack configs, you may find same nature. The config is used to modify the default behaviors.