# Why is webpack unable to find react when I'm using a custom entry point?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I set up a custom entry point in Webpack but am getting an error on this line of my React code:

`import React from 'react';`

Webpack is able to build it, but itsnt intercepting that path because Chrome gives me this console error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react".
> Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

However, when I change the path as suggested to:

`import React from './react';`

Then webpack is unable to build and gives this error:

> ERROR in ./path/to/my/file.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
> './react' in '/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/myProject/path/to/my  @
> ./path/to/my/file.js 3:0-28

And furthermore I get this Chrome console error:

> GET http://localhost:9000/path/to/my/file/react net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

So webpack is looking for react in `path/to/my/` instead of in `node_modules` as it should.

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
//snip
module.exports = {
    entry: './path/to/my/file.js',
    output: {
        path:  path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/'),
        port: 9000
    },
//snip
}
```

and `package.json`

```
{
  //snip
  "main": "path/to/my/file.js",
  //snip
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by the `<script>` tag in the HTML file pointing to the actual location of the source script, rather than pointing to the compiled output file that webpack creates.

**This is wrong:**

`<script src="/path/to/my/file.js"></script>`

^ That is pointing to the raw source code in its actual location in the repository. It isn't handled by webpack and isn't compiled by babel, it's just a plain javascript file handled by the browser, which explains the browser errors.

**This is correct:**

`<script src="bundle.js"></script>`

^ that is pointing to the compiled output that webpack generates based on the configuration. In the dev server, there **is not** an actual file called `bundle.js`, the file lives in memory, and the path to that file is just the dev server, e.g. something like `http://localhost:8000`.

The reason the name is `bundle.js` is because that's what it happens to be set to in `webpack.config.js` module output filename. If it's set to something else, it will be that.

```
output: {
  path:  path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
  publicPath: '/',
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
```