# what is the difference for directory of css files in react and in express server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ejs

for example I have a public folder that stores all the css files, and a view folder that stores the ejs files. So when I link the css file in the ejs file, I do

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”styles.css”>
```

or

```
<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”/styles.css”>
```

I don't understand how it gets the css file without me redirecting it, whereas in react I need to do e.g.

```
import "../public/styles.css"
```

which makes sense to me as I am starting from the current directory.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/27218926/2138752

Answer (score 0):

link- is a common JS syntax, and is added to the head of the HTML, optional for older browsers that doesnt recognize import.

import- es6 syntax

there is no much of difference between them, only in mechanism

Comment: I know that, but why they use different directory paths?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022695/difference-between-import-and-link-in-css#:~:text=8%20Answers&text=In%20theory%2C%20the%20only%20difference,advantage%20in%20terms%20of%20performance. read it, it might help