# External CSS is not working when linked with HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm new to programming and I've encountered some trouble linking external CSS with my HTML file. I've looked around and it appears that there may be a problem with the hierarchy of my index.html and css file/folder, but I've played around with it and don't know how to fix my problem. Any suggestions would be great!

[image]

Comment: `../css/styles.css` is the path you need because your `index.html` is in a directory.

Comment: try ../css/styles.css for your absolute path

Comment: thank you both so much, that worked !!

Comment: @lou415, the comments here are correct, but please check my answer for a more detailed explanation

Comment: @lou415: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please do not include your code in images. Use code blocks for that.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file, you link to the relative path `css/styles.css` as your stylesheet. This is an explanation of how to get the right path.

A relative path links to a file relatively to the current file. Think of it like a physical path - you need to follow it to get from one place to another. These are how you navigate a relative path:

- `folder/aaaa` - Enter the directory called "folder" and look for "aaaa".
- `../` - Go back one directory - if I'm in `folder1/folder2/`, I'm going to `folder1/`.

(this is somewhat oversimplified)

Your directory structure looks like this:

```
Web Development/
├─ Bouldering/
│  ├─ ContactMe.html
│  ├─ index.html
├─ css/
│  ├─ styles.css
```

Again, think of the path as a route to your destination. In this case, you are coming from `Web Development/Bouldering/index.html` to `Web Development/css/styles.css`.

- Go from `Web Development/Bouldering/` to `Web Development/` - Your path is `../`
- Go from `Web Development/` to `Web Development/css/` - Your path is `../css/`
- Look for `styles.css` - Your final, complete relative path is `../css/styles.css`.

Lastly, change your `link` element from your HTML:

```html
...
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Bouldering Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css"> <!-- Fixed it! -->
</head>
...
```

Comment: This is good information, but there's already an answer with this info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27218879/link-a-css-on-another-folder/27218926#27218926